# calling a method from the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to discriminate some page elements (image, css, ...) on the base of what a user choose at the first page.

I use `<%=Expression%>` like this:

```
<img id="imgBackground" src='<%= this.GetLinkBasedOnUser("img/background1.jpg") %>' />
```

The method GetLinkBasedOnUser do a simple string concatenation. 
I like this way because I'm try to keep the "user interface" separate from the code.

BUT...

```
<link href="<%= this.GetLinkBasedOnUser('css/cssStyle1.css') %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Can we see you declaration of `GetLinkBasedOnUser` in the codebehind?

Comment: what is the error ? did you try to put a breakpoint in the `GetLinkBasedOnUser` ?

Comment: can you show the code behind method's signature?

Comment: Why don't you fire an event OnClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<link href='<%= this.GetLinkBasedOnUser("css/cssStyle1.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

strings in c# requires having `"` as string delimiters, not `'` (char)